# Issue with Wow Slider gallery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I am creating a simple HTML+JQUERY website. A jquery image gallery was previously available on the website. I added one more image slider using WOW Slider. As soon as I add the code for wow slider the previous image gallery gets inivisible.

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code, this is just a guess. Try changing the `#id's` to `.classes`. Like I said this is just a guess, but if your slider is set up with `#id's` you will only be able to use it once per page.

Comment: The issue had arised because of jquery conflict as there was two different sliders on same page. I used same wowslider gallery for both.